# Simple foreign key in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a simple question regarding foreign keys and mapping in Entity Framework. 
For example, I have a class RestaurantGuest:

```
public interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}    
public class RestaurantGuest : IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And class Visit in another assembly, that should have reference to the RestaurantGuest by foreign key:

```
public class Visit
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IUser Guest { get; set; }
        public int GuestId { get; set; }
}
```

The RestaurantGuestclass does not and should not have an `IList<Visit> Visits {get;set;}`

How to map it in Entity Framework?

I expected something like this (but it does not work):

```
builder.VersionedEntity<Visit>().ToTable("Visits")
        .WithRequired(v => v.Guest).ToTable("RestaurantGuests")
        .HasForeignKey(o => o.GuestId)
```

but all tutorials will suggest to do this:

```
builder.VersionedEntity<RestaurantGuest>()
         .HasMany(o => o.Visits)
         .WithRequired(v => v.Guest)
         .HasForeignKey(v => v.GuestId);
```

I don't want to add a list of Visits to the RestaurantGuest. RestaurantGuest should not know anything about the visits.

Comment: Did you try without fluent API configuration? As per the naming conventions, this model will work as you expect without any configuration.

Comment: Please excuse me for the stupid question, but what's the `VersionedEntity` method? I don't know such method in Entity Framework, are talking about NHibernate?

Comment: @IvaStoev It is Entity Framework method. I know how to do what I want in NHibernate)) But in now days we have Entity Framework and as I understood it is impossible to do it without workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Guest` is actually an Interface, I guess you can't map it directly, because first of all you can't even assume it'll be always a RestaurantGuest.

I like using a factory like this:

```
public interface IUser
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantGuest : IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestFactory Guest { get; set; }
    public int GuestId { get; set; }
}

public class GuestFactory: IUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IUser Build()
    {
        return new RestaurantGuest { Id = this.Id };
    }
}

builder.VersionedEntity().HasMany()
       .WithRequired(v => v.Restaurant).HasForeignKey(v => v.RestaurantId);
```

Inside the `build` method, you apply whatever logic you need to instantiate the proper concrete class, in your case a `RestaurantGuest`. You configure it like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<GuestFactory>().ToTable("RestaurantGuest");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Visit>()
            .HasRequired(v => v.Guest)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(v => v.GuestId);

    }
```

And when you ran a migration of this, this is the output:

```
public partial class RestaurantTest : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.RestaurantGuest",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Visits",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    GuestId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.RestaurantGuest", t => t.GuestId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.GuestId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Visits", "GuestId", "dbo.RestaurantGuest");
        DropIndex("dbo.Visits", new[] { "GuestId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Visits");
        DropTable("dbo.RestaurantGuest");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i had a bad example first time. Please, take a look again to the question.

Comment: Oh, now I understood what you want.

Comment: @Konstantin I've updated my answer, so it fits your needs. Please, note that it's impossible for Entity Framework to automatically instantiate your Guest since it's an interface, and it doesn't know what concrete class to use, that's why I used a factory as a workaround, since you are the only who knows what concrete class to instante as a Guest. Let me know if this helps you, and if you have any further questions.

Comment: @Konstantin did it help you? If yes, you could consider marking my answer as accepted. If not, let me know what issues did you find.